# reverse proxy to local webapplication , which port must be open by iptables?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, reverse-proxy, port

I want using reverse proxy (nginx or apache) for my tomcat application.
I want redirect the ports 80,443 from reverse proxy to tomcat ports 8080, 8443.
After setting up the reverse proxy, which port must be open for inbound & outbound ?

is that right ?
 iptables inbound : open Port 80, 443 
 iptables outbound: open  Port 8080,8443

kind regards

blackbeard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) connection is always between two (not more) participants. Each one is identified with an IP address **and** a port. So in reality, when you are using a reverse proxy, you have:

- A connection between the client `<client_IP>:<random_port>` and **nginx** `<server_public_IP>:80` through you physical interface.
- A connections between **nginx** `127.0.0.1:80` and **Tomcat** `127.0.0.1:8080` through the [loopback interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost).

There is no reason for a firewall to block communication on the loopback interface. So you probably want to allow incoming traffic with **destination** port `80` and `443` and outbound traffic with **source** port `80` and `443`.

However, usually, outbound traffic is **not** blocked (policy `ACCEPT`), you just need the following iptables rules:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT # loopback interface
# don't block existing traffic
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m comment nginx -j ACCEPT
# Probably you want to allow ssh
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m comment SSH -j ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

**PS**: You can also run **Tomcat** directly on ports `80` and `443` with the same firewall rules.

Comment: thx Piotr P. , i wanted only know the open Port .:) but great ;)

Comment: I believe, it is important to understand, why ports `8080` and `8443` have nothing to do with your problem. If you really want to filter outbound traffic, you should easily find the rules.