# reverse proxy - understanding proxy pass - apache mod_proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, reverse-proxy, tomcat, proxypass

im running tomcat on my linux server and i want use a reverse proxy for this. After reading the manual in apacha for mod_proxy , i didnt really understand the /path in the proxypass .

i make a small example. the directory for my tomcat is /tomcat/webapp. Is then this following configuration right ?:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPass /tomcat/webapp         http://127.0.0.1:8080
ProxyPassReverse /tomcat/webapp  http://127.0.0.1:8080
</VirtualHost>
```

i would be thankful, im somebody with experience can help me out.

Comment: The path parameter is an [URI path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Examples), not a directory (filesystem path). Tomcat's `ROOT` web application will appear under the URL `http://example.com/tomcat/webapp/`.

Comment: this means i should change the following setting to : ProxyPass /app http://localhost:8080/tomcat/webapp right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically whichever `ProxyPass` directive you choose, it will work, even if you choose to proxy `http://example.com:8080/webapp/` as `http://example.com/foo/bar/baz/`.

However, if your application uses absolute paths in hyperlinks, it is better to use the same URI path on both **Apache** and **Tomcat** or you will have problems like in [this question](https://serverfault.com/q/998655/530633). So:

- if your application is well written, choose your favourite URL and adjust the webapp deployment on Tomcat to fit it.
- if your application is badly written (e.g. has some hardcoded paths like in [this question](https://serverfault.com/q/994736/530633) adjust the **Apache** path to fit the hardcoded deployment path.

Either way you should use:

```
ProxyPass "/path/to/webapp/" "http://127.0.0.1:8080/path/to/webapp/"
```

**PS**: Since apparently you want to [run Tomcat on two ports](https://serverfault.com/q/1000279/530633), it is better if you tell the webapp that it is being proxied and that port `8443` is accessed through SSL:

```
<Connector port="8080"
           proxyName="example.com"
           proxyPort="80"
           redirectPort="443" />
<Connector port="8443"
           proxyName="example.com"
           proxyPort="443"
           scheme="https" secure="true" />
```

so the webapp will not generate useless redirects from port `8443` to port `443`.

Comment: and what if i config the proxypass like this, :

ProxyPass /        http://127.0.0.1:8080

is it secure enough like the above examples ?

Comment: Yes, the app will work correctly. However if you want to give Tomcat the entire web space, why don't you just run Tomcat on port `80` and `443`?

Comment: for port 80/443 i need to be run tomcat as root, therefore i need to be run tomcat with reverse proxy :D

Comment: Not really: you can use [authbind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authbind) or set the `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE` ambient capability on the Tomcat process. Debian 9 uses the first, Debian 10 uses the second.

Comment: but i can still use authbind but its not secure enough, i would give tomcat user the read write execute as for all privileg ports :)

Comment: authbind is configurable and allows to bind only the specified ports. As for privileged ports: once upon a time servers trusted communication from ports lower than 1024, nowadays it is not the case.

Comment: look at debian changelog, authbind 2.1 is unstable ;), is that enough ? I read from expert, that tells me that authbind can open ports etc... (im not expert, you see ), but install apache reverse proxy, harden it, isnt much work for me, i dont understand the proxypass story, but you explain it to me very well,  know i think i understand it right :D
here the link :https://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs//main/a/authbind/authbind_2.1.2_changelog

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103687/discussion-between-piotr-p-karwasz-and-beard-black).